# How to shuffle cards in a loop and print them

Tags: java

Hi I'm trying to shuffle the cards randomly and print the "top" four cards and my teacher told me to to think of the shuffle loop as a swap but im not sure im getting it right. any help would be appreciated.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) 
{
   //Random number generator for shuffle 

    Random rand = new Random();

   //Explaining the program

   System.out.println("This program is meant to create a deck of cards and to show the top 4 cards");

   //All Arrays

   int [] deck = new int [52];
   String [] suits = new String []{"Hearts, Spades, Clubs, Diamonds"};
   String [] faceValue = new String []{"Ace, 2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10, Jack, Queen, King"};

   //Filling the deck

   for(int index = 0; index < deck.length; index ++)
   {
       deck[index] = index+1;
       //System.out.println(deck[index]);
   }

   //Shuffle the deck

    for(int i =0; i<deck.length; i ++)
   {
       int temp = rand.nextInt(51)+1;
       deck[i] = temp;
       deck[i] = deck[temp];
       deck[i] = temp;
       //System.out.println(deck[i]);


   }
    //Display
   for(int index = 0; index<4;index++)
   {
       String suit;
       String face;
       suit = suits[deck[index]/13];
       face= faceValue[deck[index]%13];
       System.out.println("Your cards are:\n");


   }
```

Comment: Look at Fisher Yates algorithm for random shuffling

Comment: Well.. I'd suggest [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle-java.util.List-), but since its a school assignment your likely supposed to implement it yourself

Comment: "The code I wrote for my assignment isn't working" is not a question.  It's a story.  And it's not even an interesting story.  Please learn some [basic debugging techniques](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and feel free to come back when you have a specific question for us.

Comment: To put 4 or 13 strings into a string array, you need to put quotes around *each* string (not just around all of them). To swap 2 array elements, you need to put one of them into a temporary variable outside the array while moving the other one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int temp = rand.nextInt(51)+1;
deck[i] = temp;
deck[i] = deck[temp];
deck[i] = temp;
```

This doesn't shuffle anything. It doesn't even use an element of the array as the final array element.

You could achieve the same effect here with

```
deck[i] = rand.nextInt(51)+1;
```

---

Instead of - whatever your're trying to do in this loop, you should approach the problem like this:

```
for i = deck.length-1, deck.length-2, ..., 2, 1
    select j uniformly at random from 0, 1, ..., i-1, i
    swap elements at indices j and i
```

This way after the loop iteration, you've chosen the elements at indices `>=i` and you only consider the rest of the elements in later iterations

or in java code:

```
for (int i = deck.length-1; i > 0; i--) {
    int j = rand.nextInt(i+1);
    int temp = deck[i];
    deck[i] = deck[j];
    deck[j] = temp;
}
```

---

Furthermore note that printing the array can fail, if you initialize the deck like this:

```
for(int index = 0; index < deck.length; index ++)
{
   deck[index] = index+1;
}
```

If the last element is among the first 4 elements after shuffling, you use `4 = 52/13` as index for the `suits` array, which leads to a `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Instead you need to initialize the indices like this:

```
for(int index = 0; index < deck.length; index++) {
   deck[index] = index;
}
```

---

Also you use arrays containing single strings instead of using arrays with multiple elements:

```
String [] suits = new String []{"Hearts", "Spades", "Clubs", "Diamonds"};
String [] faceValue = new String []{"Ace", "2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10", "Jack", "Queen", "King"};
```

Answer (score 0):

To swap two values you have to do this:

```
temp = a;
a = b;
b = temp;
```

So in your case you should have two temporary variables - `temp` and `rand`. The `rand` will mean the index of card that will be swapped with our current card.

```
int rand = rand.nextInt(51) + 1;
temp = deck[i];
deck[i] = deck[rand];
deck[i] = temp;
```